# PhoneGap + RESTful Server in Codeigniter (Response Headers, but Response Empty)

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, codeigniter-2

I have a Server running with Codeigniter and im using the REST API of Phil Sturgeon. The controller works fine, i consume the service using SOAPUI and works perfect, but when i do it in a page with JQuery Mobile and debugging with Firebug, the server return Headers Response, but no Response at all. I change URL, tried with graph facebook api and the page works, i do almost everything. Why with my service doesnt work. What is the reason for that??. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am using phonegap-1.8 (cordova-1.8.0.js) and I found that I had to edit `res\xml\cordova.xml` to add:

```
<access origin="http://mydomain.com*"/>
```

just below the existing `access origin="http://127.0.0.1*"`.